# Shoulder Steak vs London Broil

Tags: meat, steak, broiling

I bought a piece of shoulder steak. Can I cook it like a london broil - marinating it and then broiling for around fifteen minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I cook it like a london broil - marinating it and then broiling for around fifteen minutes?

[London broil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_broil) is traditionally prepared using flank steak, but the technique works well for other lean/tough cuts. Your shoulder steak may have more connective tissue than one would typically find in a flank or skirt steak, but not so much that most would find it a problem.

Marinating and grilling or broiling along the lines of London broil will work fine, as long as you're prepared to accept the extra gristle. Otherwise, consider a longer braising approach to break down the connective tissue.

For more information, see e.g.:
[Shoulder Steak](https://www.beefitswhatsfordinner.com/cuts/cut/2528/shoulder-steak)
[What is Shoulder Steak? What is it Good For? How do You Cook it?](https://www.foodfirefriends.com/shoulder-steak/)
[Which cuts of beef are suitable for slow cooking methods?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43388/which-cuts-of-beef-are-suitable-for-slow-cooking-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Shoulder steak & London broil are often used interchangeably. I won't bother with technical/pedantic differences, as practically speaking, the exact same cut of meat may be labeled "shoulder steak" at one grocer and "London broil" at another.

So yes, your shoulder steak *is* what you are used to seeing as London broil. So you can cook it exactly the same.

Comment: London broil is traditionally _flank_ steak, not shoulder. Of course, other cuts are sometimes substituted, but it would be definitely wrong to claim that London broil is in fact synonymous with shoulder steak. I wouldn't even go so far as to say the terms are _often_ used interchangeably, though I'm sure it does happen. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_broil